# 90's sci-fi book series, humanity is attacked by aliens, point of view switches between the humans' and the aliens' between books

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm attempting to find the name of a book series that I read in the mid 90's that was (I believe) new at the time.   It is either a 2 or 3 part series in which humanity is attacked by an alien race (not very specific I know).

I distinctly remember the first book being told from the perspective of the humans and the second book was told from the perspective of the aliens that attacked.  I seem to recall that it was a trilogy, but I don't remember whose perspective it was for it.

Comment: I'm intrigued about the third book's perspective if it's already been from the POV of the humans *and* the aliens.

Comment: I was thinking of StarCraft novels, but those are too late.

Comment: The first book of [Michael McCollum's *Antares* trilogy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/187052/78630) is told from the point of humans, while the second book deals substantially with the aliens' perspective.  If this looks right, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: This is a real reach but possible Turtledove’s Worldwar series? Aliens invade in the middle of WWII. Ring a bell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could you be thinking of Timothy Zahn's [*Conquerors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquerors%27) trilogy?

It dates from 1994; the first book deals with a race of aliens attacking a human empire; while the second book is mainly told from the perspective of the aliens.

If it serves to jog your memory further, the aliens have ships that seem to be almost indestructible, and have much faster communications thanks to their Elders.

There's a much better [summary of the first novel](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00WPQHJLK/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1) on Amazon:

> Timothy Zahn, Hugo Award-winning author of The New York Times best-selling Star Wars trilogy, blazes a spectacular new path across the sky in an epic original novel of star-spanning action adventure, mystery and intrigue.  A long era of peace and prosperity in the interstellar Commonwealth has suddenly come to an end.  Four alien starships of unknown origin have attacked, without provocation, an eight-ship Peacemaker task force, utterly destroying it in six savage minutes.  The authorities claim there were no survivors.  But Lord Stewart Cavanaugh, a former member of Parliament, has learned through back channels that one man may have survived to be captured by the aliens:  his son, Commander Pheylan Cavanaugh.  A large-scale invasion appears imminent, and the strictest security measures are in effect . . . measures that Lord Cavanaugh has no choice but to defy.  He recruits Adam Quinn, who once flew with the elite Copperheads--fighter pilots whose minds are literally one with their machines--to rescue his son.  Quinn assembles a crack force of Copperheads to steal out of the Commonwealth security zone and snatch Pheylan Cavanaugh from the conquerors.  Depending on the outcome, Quinn and his men will retum home as heroes or as the galaxy's most despised traitors--if they come home at all.

Comment: That would be it.  I don't know why I couldn't think of it. I love Zahn as an Author.  thank you